# Header("Location: ") ошибка: Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent

Tags: php

> Warning: Cannot modify header
> information - headers already sent by
> (output started at
> Z:\home\race.mobi\www\index.php:30) in
> Z:\home\race.mobi\www\index.php on
> line 46

Что это за ошибка?

Comment: header нужно использовать до любого вывода в браузер

Comment: А почему бы не погуглить?

------------

ИМХО Denwer хлам

Comment: При чём тут Денвер?

Comment: не причем, но все равно хлам)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Данная ошибка возникает, если перед вызовом header есть вывод чего-либо. Если Вы уверены, что до header ничего не выводится, значит скорее всего это BOM. Тогда попробуйте сохранить файл в кодировке "UTF-8 без BOM" в Notepad++. Либо ручками в WinHEX удалите.

Comment: спасибо! у меня выводиться до!

Answer (score 0):

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at Z:\home\race.mobi\www\index.php:30) in Z:\home\race.mobi\www\index.php on line 46

перевод

Предупреждение: Не могу модифицировать заголовок - заголовки уже отправлены (вывод начался в :\home\race.mobi\www\index.php:30) в Z:\home\race.mobi\www\index.php на строке 46.